# Android Ogg artist with any media player?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, ogg

Android Froyo (I'm using T-Mobile G2X) shows half my music library as having "unknown artist". Apparently that's because for years Android can't pull artist information correctly out of Ogg files. It's not just a player problem---all the player apps I've tried use the same Android library, so they all show "unknown artist".

This is really irritating, especially after painstakingly making sure all my Ogg files have correct artist info. How can I get Android to get the correct artist info into its databases? I'll gladly pay for a program to do this. Am I really going to have to sit down, get out the Android source code, and build my own distribution just to get such basic functionality? (How do these things get released?)

P.S. Don't even ask me about the lack of search-by-genre in the stock player...

Answer (score -1):

Hi all my music is in the .ogg format i use Mp3tag v2.49 from http://www.mp3tag.de/en/ to put the artist infomation into the file and i use playerPro from the market to play the songs it can read all the info and the album art. Its the only player i can find that will do this

Comment: My artist information is already in the files. I don't want to retag all my files just because Android is buggy. The files are correct---Android isn't. I want to fix the problem without modifying my files.